# No. of paths in integer array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

There is an integer array, for eg.

{3,1,2,7,5,6}

One can move forward through the array either each element at a time or can jump a few elements based on the value at that index. For e.g., one can go from 3 to 1 or 3 to 7, then one can go from 1 to 2 or 1 to 2(no jumping possible here), then one can go 2 to 7 or 2 to 5, then one can go 7 to 5 only coz index of 7 is 3 and adding 7 to 3 = 10 and there is no tenth element.

I have to only count the number of possible paths to reach the end of the array from start index.

I could only do it recursively and naively which runs in exponential time.

Somebody plz help.

Comment: as recommendation : use dp

Comment: How do you know what is allowed or not, is that knowledge only in that text or is the knowledge built into the numbers?

Comment: That is how you are supposed to traverse the array

Comment: Use a directed graph, graph theory should tell you how to count all possible paths through the graph.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen How do you do it using graphs?

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation: use dynamic programming.

**If this key word is sufficient and you want the challenge to find a possible solution on your own, dont read any further!**

Here a possible DP-algorithm on the example input `{3,1,2,7,5,6}`. It will be your job to adjust on the general problem.

create array `sol` length 6 with just zeros in it. the array will hold the number of ways.

```
sol[5] = 1;
for (i = 4; i>=0;i--) {
     sol[i] = sol[i+1];
     if (i+input[i] < 6 && input[i] != 1)
         sol[i] += sol[i+input[i]];             
}

return sol[0];
```

runtime O(n)

**As for the directed graph solution hinted in the comments :**

Each cell in the array represents a node. Make an directed edge from each node to the node accessable. Basically you can then count more easily the number of ways by just looking at the outdegrees on the nodes (since there is no directed cycle) however it is a lot of boiler plate to actual program it.

**Adjusting the recursive solution**

another solution would be to pruning. This is basically equivalent to the DP-algorithm. The exponentiel time comes from the fact, that you calculate values several times. Eg function is `recfunc(index)`. The initial call `recFunc(0)` calls `recFunc(1) and recFunc(3)` and so on.  However `recFunc(3)` is bound to be called somewhen again, which leads to a repeated recursive calculation. To prune this you add a Map to hold all already calculated values. If you make a call `recFunc(x)` you lookup in the map if `x` was already calculated. If yes, return the stored value. If not, calculate, store and return it. This way you get a O(n) too.

Comment: "Adjusting the recursive solution"-- isn't that called memoization??

Comment: yes it is called that way, but i didnt want to add more technical terms than necessary.